# how to combine data json?

Tags: c#, json

I have json data

1st data:

```css
"Data1":[
{"questionText":"Mudah 1",
"imageUrl":"Gambar1",
"answers":[
{"answerText":"A","isCorrect":true},
{"answerText":"B","isCorrect":false},
{"answerText":"C","isCorrect":false},
{"answerText":"D","isCorrect":false}]},

]
```

2nd data:

```css
"Data2":[
{"questionText":"Mudah 2",
"imageUrl":"Gambar2",
"answers":[
{"answerText":"A","isCorrect":true},
{"answerText":"B","isCorrect":false},
{"answerText":"C","isCorrect":false},
{"answerText":"D","isCorrect":false}]},

]
```

What I want to do

```css
"DataCombine":[
{"questionText":"Mudah 1",
"imageUrl":"Gambar1",
"answers":[
{"answerText":"A","isCorrect":true},
{"answerText":"B","isCorrect":false},
{"answerText":"C","isCorrect":false},
{"answerText":"D","isCorrect":false}]},
{"questionText":"Mudah 2",
"imageUrl":"Gambar2",
"answers":[
{"answerText":"A","isCorrect":true},
{"answerText":"B","isCorrect":false},
{"answerText":"C","isCorrect":false},
{"answerText":"D","isCorrect":false}]},

]
```

what should I do to combine those data?

Comment: What's this got to do with c#?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you want to do this is C# then basically your data structures are the same, but your first JSON has 1 entry, then 2nd also has one entry and you want an output which has 2 entries.

If I also assume that in your real data (I assume this is not your real data, as the JSON is actually not valid!) that you have the same data structure names then you can do the following.

First define your classes

```
public class Answer
{
    public string answerText { get; set; }
    public bool isCorrect { get; set; }
}

public class MyData
{
    public string questionText { get; set; }
    public string imageUrl { get; set; }
    public List<Answer> answers { get; set; }
}

public class RootObject
{
    public List<MyData> Data { get; set; }
}
```

Now you can deserialise, combine and serialise as follows

```
string data1 = "{ \"Data\": [{   \"questionText\": \"Mudah 1\",   \"imageUrl\": \"Gambar1\",   \"answers\": [{     \"answerText\": \"A\",     \"isCorrect\": true    },    {     \"answerText\": \"B\",     \"isCorrect\": false    },    {     \"answerText\": \"C\",     \"isCorrect\": false    },    {     \"answerText\": \"D\",     \"isCorrect\": false    }   ]  } ]}";
string data2 = "{ \"Data\": [{  \"questionText\": \"Mudah 2\",  \"imageUrl\": \"Gambar2\",  \"answers\": [{    \"answerText\": \"A\",    \"isCorrect\": true   },   {    \"answerText\": \"B\",    \"isCorrect\": false   },   {    \"answerText\": \"C\",    \"isCorrect\": false   },   {    \"answerText\": \"D\",    \"isCorrect\": false   }  ] }]}";

RootObject d1 = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(data1);
RootObject d2 = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(data2);

d1.Data.AddRange(d2.Data);

string OutJson = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(d1);
```

Comment: Sorry for my long response. This is really helpful. I just found out howto fix my project with calling each data json which u describbe.  Thanks for answer.